# Sitecore Infrastructure/Application/Solution-Shared Dashboard

Tags: azure, sitecore-rocks

We want to establish a tool (dashboard) that can give us a complete overview of the current state of our solution. Not only the infrastructure and not only the application, but a mixed details of the entire application and solution. I.e. we need values from Azure portal (Database usage), values from Sitecore (CM server load time, CD server load time, Top 10 error logs, Sitecore jobs), and also values from VSTS build (last 5 builds in each environments)
Please help if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a launchpad button to a custom application.

In the `core` database, create an item under `/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/Buttons`.  You can use normal Sitecore security on this item to control who should and should not have access to this application.

On the new Launchpad Button, set your Icon and Text appropriately.  For the behavior, set your Link field to something like  `/sitecore/shell/applications/custom/solution` (can be any endpoint really) and select OpenIframe.

Then you can register a route to listen for `/sitecore/shell/application/custom/solution`, and tie that back to a controller and Razer view.  From here it's a matter of developing your application to expose what you need.

Alternatively, you could use a paid tool like New Relic, and expose it as a launchpad application.